# Accessing expression data in an ExpressionSet

Tags: bioconductor, microarray

I used `rma` from the oligo package to normalize CEL files, returning an object of class `ExpressionSet`. How do I access the actual expression data?

```
> data = read.celfiles(names)
> data2 = oligo::rma(data)
class(data2)
[1] "ExpressionSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"
> data3 = as.matrix(data2)
Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `oligo::rma` documentation? Can you clarify why this doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

The class of your object which the `rma` function returns is an `ExpressionSet` which is a standardized data structure in Bioconductor/R from the Biobase package.

It stores both expression (a numeric matrix) data as well as column- and row annotation data.
You have to use the getter function `exprs()` to access the expression data slot, so `exprs(data2)` which is then of class `matrix`, link to [documentation](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Biobase/inst/doc/ExpressionSetIntroduction.pdf).